# Exporting and Importing Realm DB File after deleting and installing the App

Tags: ios, swift, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I have implemented Realm in our iOS app and it's working fine so far. Now we have a request to be able to delete the app, install it again and load the old Realm file (with all of it's data).

So the flow would look something like this:

- Export Realm somewhere (maybe to iCloud as a whole file or as a CSV and etc.)
- Delete the app (the realm file should still be on iCloud)
- Install the app
- Load Realm File from iCloud (also merge with existing file if some new data was created considering that the schema wasn't messed with). For example I can have a list of calls, delete the app, install the app again, create several new calls, import old file and as the end result to have the list of old and new calls altogether.

Does anyone have experience with this? Didn't have any luck googling it or on Realm website.

Comment: do a quick search with `realm icloud backup` gives many result, have you tried any?

Comment: Yes, they are all questions as well. Also I have specific flow (deleting the app, merging 2 realm files with the same schema after installing the app again, exporting to iCloud only on the user request).

Comment: I think it probably will be 1 file, since if you specify the path just like using normal Realm, you will be using the one you backed up when you delete and reinstall it

Comment: Hi Pavle. Have you considered trying out [Realm Mobile Platform](https://realm.io/products/realm-mobile-platform/)? It does pretty much exactly what you've described above (backup and restore Realm, including merging in user edits after reinstall).

Comment: @Tj3n, yes that was my idea as well (backup entire file and download it after app reinstall) and I wanted to check if this was correct approach. Still it doesn't solve my problem of merging two realm files (it will replace the old one if the user has made some new data, like new calls etc) and I want them altogether to show (old and new).

Comment: I did everything from above using ignoring iCloud (I used dropbox and google drive API). So I uploaded "myApp.realm" file do dropbox account, deleted the app, retrieved it back and that solved my problem.

Comment: @PavleMijatovic Hey, I want to achieve a similar thing in my chatting application. This is what I"m planning to try:
1. Export the realm file to the cloud (User's own drive)
2. Download these files when user login and replace them with newly created realm files.
Can you please show me a pathline here.